# TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 20, file "Move")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Running into the above message when trying to run the script below.

My objective is to have each new row from "validated" sheet to be duplicated to the next sheet "processing" once the user has selected "approve" from the dropdown in column L. And also delete from Source(validated) spreadsheet once it's moved over to "processing"

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('VALIDATED'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('L:L'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('PROCESSING'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in L:L; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Approved') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

//Delete matched rows in the source sheet
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);

//Alter j to account for deleted rows
  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: If the error occurs at ``csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)``, I think that ``data`` becomes ``[]``, and the error occurs at ``data[0].length`` because ``data`` is ``[]``. Can you confirm about this? By the way, although I think that this might be not directly related to the error, ``testvalue`` is 2 dimensional array. So please modify to ``if ( testvalue[i][0] == 'Approved') {``. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Was your issue resolved? If it was resolved, can I ask you about the reason of the issue? I would like to study from it. If your issue has not been resolved, can you provide your current situation?

Comment: Hi there, not yet. Doest give me any errors but I think its my other script running paralel to it. I'm bussy looking for simpler solutions. Will let you know hen I find a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for it.